# How to Style WinUi 3 RadioButtons as a group of toggle buttons?

Tags: c#, radio-button, winui-3, togglebutton

I need to style some grouped radio buttons as toggle buttons like below, how to implement this in WinUi

Here is the question to do the same in WPF.
[Style WPF radio button as toggle button with correct IsEnabled behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42089140/style-wpf-radio-button-as-toggle-button-with-correct-isenabled-behaviour)

[image]

```
  <StackPanel >
      <RadioButtons Header="Options:" MaxColumns="3">
          <RadioButton Content="Option 1" Checked="RadioButton_Checked" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="Option1RadioButton"/>
          <RadioButton Content="Option 2" Checked="RadioButton_Checked" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="Option2RadioButton"/>
          <RadioButton Content="Option 3" Checked="RadioButton_Checked" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="Option3RadioButton"/>
      </RadioButtons>
  </StackPanel>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get a group of toggle buttons to act like radio buttons in WinUI3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78020492/how-to-get-a-group-of-toggle-buttons-to-act-like-radio-buttons-in-winui3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```xml
<RadioButtons>
    <RadioButtons.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="RadioButton">
            <Style.Setters>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="RadioButton">
                            <ToggleButton
                                Content="{x:Bind Content, Mode=OneWay}"
                                IsChecked="{x:Bind IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style.Setters>
        </Style>
    </RadioButtons.Resources>
    <RadioButton
        AutomationProperties.AutomationId="Option1RadioButton"
        Checked="RadioButton_Checked"
        Content="Option 1" />
    <RadioButton
        AutomationProperties.AutomationId="Option2RadioButton"
        Checked="RadioButton_Checked"
        Content="Option 2" />
    <RadioButton
        AutomationProperties.AutomationId="Option3RadioButton"
        Checked="RadioButton_Checked"
        Content="Option 3" />
</RadioButtons>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could define custom style for the `RadioButton`:

```
<Style TargetType="RadioButton">
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonBackground}" />
    <Setter Property="BackgroundSizing" Value="InnerBorderEdge" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonForeground}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonBorderBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonBorderThemeThickness}" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="{StaticResource ButtonPadding}" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}" />
    <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="{StaticResource UseSystemFocusVisuals}" />
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualMargin" Value="-3" />
    <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="{ThemeResource ControlCornerRadius}" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="RadioButton">
                <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter"
                  Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                  BackgroundSizing="{TemplateBinding BackgroundSizing}"
                  BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                  BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                  Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                  ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                  ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
                  CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding CornerRadius}"
                  Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                  HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                  VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                  AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw">
                    <ContentPresenter.BackgroundTransition>
                        <BrushTransition Duration="0:0:0.083" />
                    </ContentPresenter.BackgroundTransition>

                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />

                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">

                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonBackgroundPointerOver}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonBorderBrushPointerOver}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonForegroundPointerOver}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>

                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">

                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonBackgroundPressed}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonBorderBrushPressed}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonForegroundPressed}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>

                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">

                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonBackgroundDisabled}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonForegroundDisabled}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonBorderBrushDisabled}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>

                            <VisualState x:Name="Checked">

                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonBackgroundChecked}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonForegroundChecked}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonBorderBrushChecked}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BackgroundSizing">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonCheckedStateBackgroundSizing}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="CheckedPointerOver">

                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonBackgroundCheckedPointerOver}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonBorderBrushCheckedPointerOver}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonForegroundCheckedPointerOver}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BackgroundSizing">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonCheckedStateBackgroundSizing}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="CheckedPressed">

                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonBackgroundCheckedPressed}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonForegroundCheckedPressed}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonBorderBrushCheckedPressed}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BackgroundSizing">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonCheckedStateBackgroundSizing}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="CheckedDisabled">

                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonBackgroundCheckedDisabled}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonForegroundCheckedDisabled}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonBorderBrushCheckedDisabled}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Indeterminate">

                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonBackgroundIndeterminate}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonForegroundIndeterminate}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonBorderBrushIndeterminate}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="IndeterminatePointerOver">

                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonBackgroundIndeterminatePointerOver}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonBorderBrushIndeterminatePointerOver}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonForegroundIndeterminatePointerOver}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="IndeterminatePressed">

                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonBackgroundIndeterminatePressed}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonBorderBrushIndeterminatePressed}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonForegroundIndeterminatePressed}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="IndeterminateDisabled">

                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonBackgroundIndeterminateDisabled}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonForegroundIndeterminateDisabled}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonBorderBrushIndeterminateDisabled}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>

                        </VisualStateGroup>

                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                </ContentPresenter>

            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```