# How to get a group of toggle buttons to act like radio buttons in WinUI3?

Tags: c#, radio-button, winui-3, togglebutton

How to get a group of toggle buttons to act like radio buttons in WinUI3?

For the example below, how to implement following UI behavior:

1. You can make the one of four toggle buttons checked by clicking it, and at same time uncheck the other 3 buttons.
2. You cannot uncheck a checked toggle button by clicking it.

[image]

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <ToggleButton x:Name="Toggle1" Content="ToggleButton"
        IsEnabled="{x:Bind DisableToggle1.IsChecked.Value.Equals(x:False), Mode=OneWay}"
        Checked="ToggleButton_Checked" Unchecked="ToggleButton_Unchecked" />
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of setting `IsEnabled`, I'd set `IsHitTestVisible` like this:

```xml
<StackPanel x:Name="ToggeButtons">
    <ToggleButton
        Checked="ToggleButton_Checked"
        Content="1" />
    <ToggleButton
        Checked="ToggleButton_Checked"
        Content="2" />
    <ToggleButton
        Checked="ToggleButton_Checked"
        Content="3" />
    <ToggleButton
        Checked="ToggleButton_Checked"
        Content="4" />
</StackPanel>
```

```cs
private void ToggleButton_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is not ToggleButton checkedToggleButton)
    {
        return;
    }

    foreach (ToggleButton toggleButton in ToggeButtons.Children.OfType<ToggleButton>())
    {
        toggleButton.IsChecked = toggleButton == checkedToggleButton;
        toggleButton.IsHitTestVisible = toggleButton != checkedToggleButton;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the functionality of a `RadioButton`, then use a `RadioButton` and modify its template to make it look like you want, like for example a `ToggleButton`.

Here is a XAML-only example:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="RadioButton">
            <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonBackground}" />
            <Setter Property="BackgroundSizing" Value="InnerBorderEdge" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonForeground}" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonBorderBrush}" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonBorderThemeThickness}" />
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="{StaticResource ButtonPadding}" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}" />
            <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="{StaticResource UseSystemFocusVisuals}" />
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualMargin" Value="-3" />
            <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="{ThemeResource ControlCornerRadius}" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="RadioButton">
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter"
              Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
              BackgroundSizing="{TemplateBinding BackgroundSizing}"
              BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
              BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
              Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
              ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
              ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
              CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding CornerRadius}"
              Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
              HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
              VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
              AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw">
                            <ContentPresenter.BackgroundTransition>
                                <BrushTransition Duration="0:0:0.083" />
                            </ContentPresenter.BackgroundTransition>

                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />

                                    <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">

                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonBackgroundPointerOver}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonBorderBrushPointerOver}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonForegroundPointerOver}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>

                                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">

                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonBackgroundPressed}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonBorderBrushPressed}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonForegroundPressed}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>

                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">

                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonBackgroundDisabled}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonForegroundDisabled}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonBorderBrushDisabled}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>

                                    <VisualState x:Name="Checked">

                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonBackgroundChecked}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonForegroundChecked}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonBorderBrushChecked}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BackgroundSizing">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonCheckedStateBackgroundSizing}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="CheckedPointerOver">

                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonBackgroundCheckedPointerOver}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonBorderBrushCheckedPointerOver}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonForegroundCheckedPointerOver}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BackgroundSizing">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonCheckedStateBackgroundSizing}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="CheckedPressed">

                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonBackgroundCheckedPressed}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonForegroundCheckedPressed}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonBorderBrushCheckedPressed}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BackgroundSizing">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonCheckedStateBackgroundSizing}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="CheckedDisabled">

                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonBackgroundCheckedDisabled}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonForegroundCheckedDisabled}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonBorderBrushCheckedDisabled}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Indeterminate">

                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonBackgroundIndeterminate}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonForegroundIndeterminate}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonBorderBrushIndeterminate}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="IndeterminatePointerOver">

                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonBackgroundIndeterminatePointerOver}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonBorderBrushIndeterminatePointerOver}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonForegroundIndeterminatePointerOver}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="IndeterminatePressed">

                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonBackgroundIndeterminatePressed}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonBorderBrushIndeterminatePressed}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonForegroundIndeterminatePressed}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="IndeterminateDisabled">

                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonBackgroundIndeterminateDisabled}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonForegroundIndeterminateDisabled}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonBorderBrushIndeterminateDisabled}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>

                                </VisualStateGroup>

                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        </ContentPresenter>

                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <RadioButton x:Name="Toggle1" Content="1" GroupName="g" IsHitTestVisible="{x:Bind Toggle1.IsChecked.Value.Equals(x:False), Mode=OneWay}" />
    <RadioButton x:Name="Toggle2" Content="2" GroupName="g" IsHitTestVisible="{x:Bind Toggle2.IsChecked.Value.Equals(x:False), Mode=OneWay}" />
    <RadioButton x:Name="Toggle3" Content="3" GroupName="g" IsHitTestVisible="{x:Bind Toggle3.IsChecked.Value.Equals(x:False), Mode=OneWay}" />
    <RadioButton x:Name="Toggle4" Content="4" GroupName="g" IsHitTestVisible="{x:Bind Toggle4.IsChecked.Value.Equals(x:False), Mode=OneWay}" />
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get exactly the result you see in the picture. It is better to use tokenView from Labs

[image]

https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/Labs-Windows/issues